# DELETE view from ListView with SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm printing my SQL table with ListView, as you can see.
I'm trying to delete a selected row but can't find the position of the selected view:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> listItems;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.db = (new DBManager(this, "myDB", null, 1)).getWritableDatabase();

    listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

     this.db = (new DBManager(this, "myDB", null, 1)).getWritableDatabase();
    this.db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR,quantity INTEGER,catgory VARCHAR,warehouse VARCHAR);");

    this.cursor = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM items;", null);
    for(cursor.moveToFirst();cursor.getCount()>0 &&!cursor.isAfterLast() ;cursor.moveToNext()){
        listItems.add(cursor.getInt(0)+","+cursor.getString(1)+","+cursor.getInt(2)+","+cursor.getString(3)+","+cursor.getString(4));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: To get id - Split item( string) with "," as separator and take first item - then use delete statemant with this id

Comment: I tried it but i get the next row details from the item i selected. -1 not working as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
adapter.getItemId(put your selection here);\\
```

it should work.

Fore more info, look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

Comment: Dushyant Patel thanks for the reply but i'm getting massage : getPosition is undifined for the Type MainActivity

by the way, the selection of the line is done by checking the box.

Comment: Well it doesnt really has to be the getPosition(). I depends on what kinda of variable you have, is your variable long or int??

Comment: Which variable are you taking about ?
I need the position of the VIEW selected.

Comment: This is crap ... **ArrayAdapter** has no ids ... This will return position or position in array not id

Comment: position with INT type? i need the selection #position# for the cursor.moveToPosition(#position#);
how can i do that?

Comment: @Selvin, I didn't get time to reply quickly. My solution is is correct, just put the position you get from the check box. It has worked for me. I was not aware if he's using long or int for his database ids. I meant getPosition() for itemid you get from check box.

Comment: this is the problem i dont know how to get the position from the check box.

Comment: @DushyantPatel lol, no, it is not correct and you don't know what are you talking about ... he is using **ArrayAdapter** and it has no ids so implementation just return position, not id! https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#LC354